# Retrieve additional columns on aggregation and date operator

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following PostgreSQL table structure, which gathers temperature records for every second:

```
+----+--------+-------------------------------+---------+
| id | value  |             date              | station |
+----+--------+-------------------------------+---------+
|  1 |      0 | 2017-08-22 14:01:09.314625+02 |       1 |
|  2 |      0 | 2017-08-22 14:01:09.347758+02 |       1 |
|  3 | 25.187 | 2017-08-22 14:01:10.315413+02 |       1 |
|  4 | 24.937 | 2017-08-22 14:01:10.322528+02 |       1 |
|  5 | 25.187 | 2017-08-22 14:01:11.347271+02 |       1 |
|  6 | 24.937 | 2017-08-22 14:01:11.355005+02 |       1 |
| 18 | 24.875 | 2017-08-22 14:01:17.35265+02  |       1 |
| 19 | 25.187 | 2017-08-22 14:01:18.34673+02  |       1 |
| 20 | 24.875 | 2017-08-22 14:01:18.355082+02 |       1 |
| 21 | 25.187 | 2017-08-22 14:01:19.361491+02 |       1 |
| 22 | 24.875 | 2017-08-22 14:01:19.371154+02 |       1 |
| 23 | 25.187 | 2017-08-22 14:01:20.354576+02 |       1 |
| 30 | 24.937 | 2017-08-22 14:01:23.372612+02 |       1 |
| 31 |      0 | 2017-08-22 15:58:53.576238+02 |       1 |
| 32 |      0 | 2017-08-22 15:58:53.590872+02 |       1 |
| 33 | 26.625 | 2017-08-22 15:58:54.59986+02  |       1 |
| 38 | 26.375 | 2017-08-22 15:58:56.593205+02 |       1 |
| 39 |      0 | 2017-08-21 15:59:40.181317+02 |       1 |
| 40 |      0 | 2017-08-21 15:59:40.190221+02 |       1 |
| 41 | 26.562 | 2017-08-21 15:59:41.182622+02 |       1 |
| 42 | 26.375 | 2017-08-21 15:59:41.18905+02  |       1 |
+----+--------+-------------------------------+---------+
```

I want now to retrieve the maximum value for every hour, along with the data associated to that entry (id, date). As such, I tried the following:

```
select max(value) as m, (date_trunc('hour', date)) as d
from temperature
where station='1'
group by (date_trunc('hour', date));
```

Which works fine ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f4a2f/1)), but I only get the columns m and d as a result. If I now try to add the `date` or `id` columns to the `SELECT` statement, I get the usual `column "temperature.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` error.

I have already tried approaches such as the ones described [here](http://bernardoamc.github.io/sql/2015/05/04/group-by-non-aggregate-columns/), unfortunately to no avail, as for instance I seem to be unable to perform a join on the `date_trunc`-generated columns.

The result I am aiming for is this:

```
+----+--------+-------------------------------+---------+
| id | value  |             date              | station |
+----+--------+-------------------------------+---------+
|  3 | 25.187 | 2017-08-22 14:01:10.315413+02 |       1 |
| 33 | 26.625 | 2017-08-22 15:58:54.59986+02  |       1 |
| 41 | 26.562 | 2017-08-21 15:59:41.182622+02 |       1 |
+----+--------+-------------------------------+---------+
```

It does not matter which record was retrieved in case two or more entries have the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (date_trunc('hour', date)) *
from temperature
where station = '1'
order by date_trunc('hour', date), value desc
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f4a2f/3)

Comment: It seems that I got so focused on using max that I overlooked this option. Thanks!